# trying to center the signup form in the middle of the footer

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

[image]

I am trying to get the signup form in the footer to be exactly centered in the middle of the footer; in between the left and right side of the footer. It is too far to the left side if I try using the `push`, `pull` or `offset` classes. It just seems to go a little too far in one direction. I'm using html5, css3 and bootstrap 3. Above, I have attached an image of what I would like it to look like.

```
<footer class="footer-distributed">
  <div class="footer-left">
    <h3>Menu</h3>
    <p class="footer-links">
      <a href="#">text</a> •
      <a href="#"> text </a> •
      <a href="#"> text </a> •
      <a href="#"> text </a> •
      <a href="#"> text </a>
    </p>

    <p class="footer-company-name"> <a href="http://www.hellohello.com">hellohello</a><span> &copy; 2016</span></p>

    <div class="footer-social">
      <!-- Social Media -->
      <ul class="social">
        <li>
          <a href="http://wwww.fb.com/hellohello" class="Facebook">
            <i class="ion-social-facebook"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://wwww.twitter.com/ hellohello " class="Twitter">
            <i class="ion-social-twitter"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="Linkedin">
            <i class="ion-social-linkedin"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://wwww.fb.com/ hellohello " class="Google Plus">
            <i class="ion-social-googleplus"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-push-center ">
    <div class=" subscribe-foot section-wrapper">
      <p class="subscribe-nowfoot">
        Sign up for our newsletter to stay hellohello informed
        <br>about new products, updates and discounts
      </p>

      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 col-sm-push-2">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control border-radius" placeholder="Email address">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-form border-radius custom-sub-btn" type="button">Sign up</button>
    </span>
        </div>
        <!-- /input-group -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer-right">
    <p>Contact Us</p>
    <form action="#" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
      <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
      <button>Send</button>
    </form>

  </div>
</footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
#footer {
  background-color: #292c2f;
}

.footer-distributed {
  background-color: #292c2f;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  font: bold 16px sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 50px 60px 40px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Footer left */

.footer-distributed .footer-left {
  float: left;
}


/* The company logo */

.footer-distributed h3 {
  color: #bebebe;
  font: normal 36px 'roboto', sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}


/* Footer links */

.footer-distributed .footer-links {
  color: #00bfff;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  padding: 0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-links a {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1.8;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-name {
  color: #00bfff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-name span {
  color: #d1d1d1;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-name a {
  color: #00bfff;
}

.footer-distributed .subscribe-nowfoot {
  color: #eaeaea;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.footer-distributed .btn-form:hover,
.footer-distributed .btn-form:active {
  border: 1px solid #00bfff;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #00bfff;
}

.footer-distributed .custom-sub-btn {
  background-color: #00bfff;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #00bfff;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.footer-distributed .custom-sub-btn:hover {
  color: #00bfff;
  background: #fff;
  border-color: #00bfff;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.subscribe-foot {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}


/* Footer Right */

.footer-distributed .footer-right {
  float: right;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-right p {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0px 0px 20px 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  color: #bebebe;
  font: normal 36px 'roboto', sans-serif;
}


/* The contact form */

.footer-distributed form {
  display: inline-block;
}

.footer-distributed form input,
.footer-distributed form textarea {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border: none;
  resize: none;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #969696;
  width: 280px;
  padding: 18px;
}

.footer-distributed::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #5c666b;
}

.footer-distributed::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #00aaff;
  opacity: 1;
}

.footer-distributed:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #00aaff;
}

.footer-distributed form input {
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.footer-distributed form textarea {
  height: 75px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.footer-distributed form button {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #00bbff;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 0;
  padding: 8px 50px;
  font-weight: 500;
  float: right;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.footer-distributed form button:hover {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #00bbff;
  border: 2px solid #00bfff;
  padding: 8px 50px;
  font-weight: 500;
  float: right;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit weird because in the same div you're using both your own positioning (through `.footer-left` and `.footer-right`) and the grid system of bootstrap (for the sign up div). It's better (in my opinion) to stick with one of the two.

**First option, Bootstrap:**

To do it using bootstrap, you need:

- To remove the float from your css
- To add the proper class for left/right:

So the css remains mostly unchanged (just remove the float left and right) and the html has some changes. Which can be summed up as :

```
<div class="footer-left col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
    <!-- Menu -->
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <!-- Sign up -->       
</div>
<div class="footer-right col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
    <!-- Contact -->
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/_Py_/3uybymtk/

**Second option, no Bootstrap:**

Without bootstrap, I'd recommend using flex (see https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes for more info)

To use it properly in our case, it's quite simple:

- Remove the float left/right
- Remove the bootstrap code for the sign up div
- Add the proper css to make it flex.

So the html is :

```
<div class="footer-left>
    <!-- Menu -->
</div>
<div>
    <!-- Sign up -->       
</div>
<div class="footer-right">
    <!-- Contact -->
</div>
```

And the css is modified as such :

```css
.footer-distributed {
  background-color: #292c2f;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  font: bold 16px sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 50px 60px 40px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display : flex;
  justify-content : space-between;
}
.footer-distributed > div {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.footer-distributed .footer-left {
}
.footer-distributed .footer-right{
}
```

I put the footer-left and footer-right to show that they now have nothing.

This works by:

- Setting the `.footer-distributed` in a flex display (`display:flex`)
- Changing the way elements are displayed in this flex container (`justify-content : space-between` will make the first element to be at the start of the line, the last at the end of the line, and the rest spaced equally in between. i.e, our signup div will be centered!).
- Telling the div that are a direct child of `.footer-distributed` that they won't grow/shrink and that their base size is determined by their height/width (`flex: 0 0 auto;`)

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/_Py_/segk8mxt/

Comment: Worked perfect! Thanks